# Passing records between views

Tags: grails

I have a table that list information about `People`. When the user clicks on a record, i want to navigate to another view screen and display details about the record it selected.

The code is as follows:

```
<td><g:link controller="People" action="showListPeople" id="${peopleInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: peopleInstance, field: "personName")}</g:link></td>
```

1.) When i click on the above `hyperlink` the page navigates to a new View. But how do i display details of the row selected by the user in the new View ?

2.) I want to prevent users from directly accessing the view  `localhost:9900/proj/person/showListPeople` by typing or any other means it should always appear only if the user selects a record from the List view. How can i get this done ?

Answer (score 2):

Use params. Something like following

```
<g:link controller="People" action="showListPeople" id="${peopleInstance.id}" params="[foo: 'bar', bar: 'foo']"> My Link </g:link>
```

For second question, I think there is no Grails way to do that. You need to do some token strategy for that..pass a token while link creation and check for the token when user is coming from that link...if he is coming from different way that token will not be there....You can save token is memory (in session) or in DB (it will be performance hit).

Comment: 1st Question - Can say this `params="params"` so i get all the parameters?
2nd question - There was an example i read sometime back. If the user isn't logged-in when viewing a page, he/she will be redirected to the login page. Likewise isn't there any solution like that ?

Comment: No you cant set params="params" ... params is key value map...so for your case .. For instance if you need to send person name in the params, you will do like that...

params = "${[personName: fieldValue(bean: peopleInstance, field: "personName")]}"

Comment: For second question you need to install plugin spring-security-core for  what you want...

Comment: 1.) So can i use sprint-security to control the user from directly accessing the URL and redirect him to the previous screen ? 2.) How do i display the fields passed from params on the new screen. (I am a newbie and if you can show me an example it would be great)

Comment: For 1 yes...For 2...At your controller level you have action showListPeople .... pass the new filed while rendering...

render (template:'/showListPeoplePage', model: [personName: params.personName])

and on your view just write ${personName}

Comment: In regards to the second question - You could make it quite a bit harder for someone to access by using POST parameters instead of GET, which is basically what you're doing when appending the id to the end of the URL. This can be accomplished through putting the ID in a hidden field within a form. At least this way an 'attacker' would need to generate posted data instead of simply trying numbers on your URL string.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Umair's explanation regarding the first question:

In your listing view, you generate links onto the names of the people you display in the list (or you place a separate button in every row for this purpose). You generate the links in a way that they contain the people's ID as a parameter (see Umair's example link).

Your detail controller will get this request parameter and load the person entity in question and provide it to the detail view (in its model) which will display the details.

Comment: Basically, you say that i should only pass an ID, and then using that ID i should fetch the records and display ? I am retrieving the ID in my code, but how am i going to use the ID to fetch that record? A tiny code example would help.

Comment: Absolutely, this is the standard technique.